ASP.NET controller authorization policy to accept DefaultAzureCredential ManagedIdentity via bearer token
I am trying to use an Azure App Service's ManagedIdentity (via DefaultAzureCredential) to call a downstream web api controller method in a separate Azure App Service, but although I can retrieve an access token from the credential, when I use it (via HttpClient call with bearer token in authorization header) to call the controller method the call does not work when the controller method has the [Authorize] attribute (or when there is no Authorize attribute and the app is configured with services.AddAuthorization(o => o.FallbackPolicy = o.DefaultPolicy); It only works if the controller method has the [AllowAnonymous] atribute (or when the FallbackPolicy is NOT set to the DefaultPolicy). I want to use [Authorize] and do not want to use [AllowAnonymous] as I expect the ManagedIdentity to act as an authorized user and with [Authorize] (and not [AllowAnonymous]) it should be permitted to call the controller method without being treated as unauthorized and/or redirected to log in.
The downstream web api controller method is in a C# ASP.NET Core (.NET 8) MVC/WebApi/Blazor Server app hosted in an Azure App Service. The client application is a C# ASP.NET Core (.NET 8) app hosted in an Azure App Service.
I have the following key lines in my Program.cs file of the downstream app:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

Note I have also tried replacing OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme above with JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme and added .AddJwtBearer() to the above, with no success (it also prevented UI access to the downstream app's web site when testing locally). I'm not sure if when using AddJwtBearer if I need to set TokenValidationParameters including setting the IssuerSigningKey.
Here's the AzureAd section of my appsettings.json config file:
"AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "TenantId": "<tenantId>",
        "ClientId": "<App registration clientId>",
        "Scopes": "api://<clientId>/.default",
    },

From the client app I get the access token for the Managed Identity this way:
var opts = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
    ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = **false**,
    ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true,
    ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
    ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
    ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
    ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
    ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
    ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
    ExcludeWorkloadIdentityCredential = true,
    ExcludeAzureDeveloperCliCredential = true,
};
var defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(opts);
var accessToken = await defaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(
    new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
        new[] { $"api://{**clientId**}/.default" })); 

Then I set the token in a HttpRequestMessage Authorization header like this:
var uriString = "https://mydownstreamappservice.azurewebsites.net/api/mycontrollermethod";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage {
    RequestUri = new Uri(uriString), Method = HttpMethod.Get };
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken.Token}");

Then I make the call using my HttpClient instance and view the Content in the HttpResponseMessage result:
var httpRespMsg = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var resultContent = await httpRespMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

If my controller method is decorated with [AllowAnonymous], I get a message returned from the controller method. But if it is decorated with [Authorize], then I get a login.microsoft.com login web page prompting to sign in:
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>

With the controller method decorated with [Anonymous], I was expecting to get a message (string) returned from the controller method since I provided a just-retrieved access token.
I read Calling APIs with Managed Identity and tried the daemon console app calling your own API but have not been able to get the daemon console app to call the sample controller method. I was able to get the daemon console app to call my own app's controller method but had the same issue with authorization not working. Under the covers of the helper methods, the Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi library appears to do the same thing I am doing once a bearer token is obtained.
I am able to run the client and downstream apps in Visual Studio and use the VisualStudioCredential instead of the ManagedIdentity credential to get an access token and can call the downstream app (using localhost instead of mydownstreamappservice.azurewebsites.net), but I get the same issue.

I just blogged about DefaultAzureCredential at https://nestenius.se/2024/04/18/default-azure-credentials-under-the-hood/ and if you are disabling most of the tokencredentials, then you can just just the managedidentity directly or the ChainedTokenCredential.  I also blogged about debugging JwtBearer issues ere https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

I guess the managedIdentity you get is mainly for accessing Azure resources (blog storage...). To get AddJwtBearer, then AddJwtBearer needs to be told how it can trust and accept the access token provided from DefaultAzureCredential. Not sure about the proper way to do that here.
